# How to add a colon every 3 figures in a JS counter?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a server-side JS for a counter:

```
var date = new Date(2013,1,01);
var now = new Date();
var number = 0;
var increment = 3290;
var second = 1;
var secondTotal = (now.getTime()-date.getTime())/1000;
var incrementTotal = (secondTotal/1)*3290;
number = Math.round(number+incrementTotal);
function init() {
    document.getElementById("kwh_fam_an").innerHTML = number;
    setInterval('incrementation()',second*1000);
}
function incrementation() {
    number = number+increment;
    document.getElementById("kwh_fam_an").innerHTML = number;
}
```

I'm trying to change the format by forcing a colon and a space every 3 figures but the code below doesn't work:

```
function lisibilite_nombre(nbr) {
    var number = '' + nbr;
    var retour = '';
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = number.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if (count != 0 && count % 3 == 0)
            retour = number[i] + ' ' + retour ;
        else
            retour = number[i] + retour ;
        count++;
    }
    alert('nb : ' + nbr + ' => ' + retour);
    return retour;
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Also, are you sure that's serverside JS?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what your output should look like and why your code doesn't produce the expected result?

Comment: You mentioned server-side js, and your code contains alert. Could that be a problem? Your code works fine in a browser: http://jsfiddle.net/CAfVj/

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the space but not the colon.  Change:

```
retour = number[i] + ' ' + retour ;
```

to:

```
retour = number[i] + ': ' + retour;
```